# How to remember style changes?

Tags: php, jquery, css

There are so many articles about `cookies` and `localStorage` (setting, deleting...), but it's unclear for me where I should place some code.

Namely, I'm trying to change css stylesheet clicking on a button, but cannot save that choice for the next time the page is loaded. Something like:

params.php

```
if (user clicked on "btntheme") {
    $theme = 'green.css';    
}else{  
    $theme = "blue.css";
};
```

index.php

```
<?php include ("params.php");?>
<head>
<link id="link01" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $theme;?>">
</head>

<body>
<div id="btntheme">THEME</div>
</body>
```

JS

```
$('#btntheme').click(function(){
    $('#link01').attr('href', 'green.css');
});
```

This changes style but only for the current session. How can I tell to `params.php` that in the future `$theme` is `green.css`, and not `blue.css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using localStorage is very easy.

To set

```
localStorage.setItem('theme','green');
```

To get

```
localStorage.getItem('theme');
```

So you can just use that in a function to get from LS and then set your stylesheet.

```
function changeTheme(){
   var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
   $('#link01').attr('href', theme + '.css');
}

$('#btntheme').click(function(){
   localStorage.setItem('theme','green');
   changeTheme();
});
```

And you can just call that function in your `document.ready` function to set it on page load as well.

Comment: I treid, it works, but I see all elements are firstly styled by `blue.css` (about a second or two) and then `green.css` appears. Maybe this would not happen using cookies instead ?

Comment: That's probably because you're using PHP to echo the theme.  Why not handle it all in JS.  PHP is loaded and ran after the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select` element to set `localStorage` to user selected value. Use `$.holdReady(true)` to check if `localStorage` is not `null`, if a value is set at the key, set `href` of `link` element, else call `$.holdReady(false)`. Would consider setting a default `href` for `link` element for case where user does not make a selection.

html

```
<!-- set default value at `href` -->
<link id="link01" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $theme;?>">
```

```
<select>
  <option>Select a theme</option>
  <option value="green.css">Green Theme</option>
  <option value="blue.css">Blue Theme</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
$.holdReady(true);

if (localStorage.getItem("theme") !== null) {
  $("#link1").attr("href", localStoage.getItem("theme"))
}

$.holdReady(false);

$(function() {
  $("select").change(function(e) {
    $("#link1").attr("href", this.value);
    localStorage.setItem("theme", this.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: I treid, it works, but I see all elements are firstly styled by `blue.css` (about a second or two) and then `green.css` appears. Maybe this would not happen using cookies instead ?

Comment: Try substituting `<script>` element following `<link>` element for `$.holdReady()` to include `if` statement. Or, including a default `href` at `link` element and setting the default `href` at `.ready()` handler if user has not made a selection at `<select>` element.